# Evaluate the complex logarithmic function $\log(1-i)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate $\log(1-i)$.

I have $\log(1-i) = \operatorname{Log}|1-i|+i\operatorname{Arg}(1-i)+i2k\pi$

How do I compute $\operatorname{Log}|1-i|$?

Comment: It is $\rm Log \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You don't seem to be following the semi-standard distinction between $\log$ with a lower-case "l" and $\operatorname{Log}$ with a capital "L".  But you're using both lower-case and capital.  If you don't intend any distinction, that's really sloppy notation, and if you do, you should explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find $|1-i|$. That's positive real ($\left|a+bi\right|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$). Then find its log.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you compute the modulus.  Second, determine the argument.     The format is $\log(r)+i
arg(2\pi n)$. 
This is how complex logarithm is determined.